# Enter date from php form for booking from : and to : how to insert in mysql ? i tried but it only inserting current date?

Tags: php, mysql

I used this and then insert into my mysql table . but what I got is current date , I do not need current date , I need user to  pick date which should be saved in table.

```
$pick_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')];
```

Comment: your not passing a timestamp. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Can You provide your Code please ?

Answer (score 0):

Your date format must be `Y-m-d H:i:s` or column `type` is `date`  or `datetime`

```
insert into table (date) values ('2015-10-10') //column type date
```

or

```
insert into table (datetime) values ('2015-10-10 10:15') //column type datetime
```

Comment: if i ll enter  values ('2015-10-10') while inserting , the value itself will be save in table , i want user to select date , and save it in table ?

Comment: @Rida are you using any date picker?

Comment: use jquery date picker

Comment: if date format is this try this query **insert into table (date) values (str_to_date('11/09/2015','%m/%d/%Y'))**

Comment: print your MySQL query and send me

Comment: $query= "INSERT INTO bookings(name, product_id, email, address, city, country, contact, category,pick_date,drop_date, pick_loc, payMod,status) 
    VALUES ( '$name', '$product_id' , '$email'  , '$address' , '$city' , '$country' , '$contact',
      '$category','$pick_date','$drop_date' , '$pick_loc' , '$PayMod' ,'pending')";

Comment: please **echo** your query and than past

Comment: @Rida if you post your query with values it will be easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

MySQL displays the **DATE** type as `'YYYY-MM-DD'`, so you could do something like:

Suppose you are getting date from date picker as `05/11/2015`. So you will first have to convert it into MySQL format as,

```
$value = 05/11/2015
$mysql_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/','-', $value)));
```

Then you can use that value in query as

```
insert into table_name (booking_date) values ('$mysql_date')
```

Comment: what if i pick 05/12/2015 ? from textfield ? how to convert it into the $value ?

Comment: if I am not wrong, you must be using `form` for doing all these things and lets suppose the form is having `POST` method. So considering the name of text field as `txtBookingDate` you can assign it to `$value` as `$value = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['txtBookingDate']);`